# Cannot add/remove sealed array elements

Tags: vue.js, graphql, apollo

I am combining a graphql api call with an array modification.

```
async deletePhoto(photoId, driveId, index) {

  this.property.photos.splice(index, 1);

  await api.photos.remove(this.property.id, photoId, driveId);
},
```

**api call:**

```
  const remove = async (propertyId, photoId, driveId) => {

  const mutation = gql`
    mutation photoDelete($propertyId: Int!, $photoId: String!, $driveId: String!) {
      deletePropertyPhoto(propertyId: $propertyId, photoId: $photoId, driveId: $driveId)
    }
  `;

  const result = await apolloClient.mutate({
    mutation,
    variables: {
      propertyId,
      photoId,
      driveId,
    },
  });

  console.log(result);
  return result;
};
```

**Problem:**

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot add/remove sealed array elements
    at Array.splice (<anonymous>)
    at VueComponent._callee3$ (http://localhost:3030/_nuxt/3.js:284:38)
    at tryCatch (http://localhost:3030/_nuxt/vendor.bundle.5559a1f55cb4b1323e8d.js:26549:40)
    at Generator.invoke [as _invoke] (http://localhost:3030/_nuxt/vendor.bundle.5559a1f55cb4b1323e8d.js:26787:22)
    at Generator.prototype.(anonymous function) [as next] (http://localhost:3030/_nuxt/vendor.bundle.5559a1f55cb4b1323e8d.js:26601:21)
    at step (http://localhost:3030/_nuxt/vendor.bundle.5559a1f55cb4b1323e8d.js:8714:30)
    at http://localhost:3030/_nuxt/vendor.bundle.5559a1f55cb4b1323e8d.js:8732:14
    at Promise (<anonymous>)
    at F (http://localhost:3030/_nuxt/vendor.bundle.5559a1f55cb4b1323e8d.js:8036:28)
    at VueComponent.<anonymous> (http://localhost:3030/_nuxt/vendor.bundle.5559a1f55cb4b1323e8d.js:8711:12)
```

What makes this error so weird? When I remove the api call, it works fine. This doesn't make any sense to me, because the api call has nothing to do with the array modification.

**EDIT:**
This is insane, sometimes the error appears, and sometimes the splicing works just fine. This is the most random bug I've ever encountered.

**EDIT2:**
When fetching the properties (and photos) I've already made an object copy of the graphql result:

```
async asyncData({ params }) {
    const fetchedProperty = await api.properties.findOne(params.id);
    return {
      oldProperty: fetchedProperty,
      property: Object.assign({}, fetchedProperty),
    };
  },
```

Comment: afaik, graphql always returns immutable structures, either you should keep it immutable, or make a copy of their structures do mutable ones

Comment: @EvaldoBratti I understand, but as you see I'm not modifying the result of the api call. It's even before the api call. Besides that, when I first fetched the photos, I already made a copy. Please look at EDIT2.

Comment: Yes you are, `this.property` is set via the api call. You shallow copy the object using `Object.assign`, but the array set to `photos` is still sealed. You need to explicitly copy `fetchedProperty.photos` when setting `property` if you want to edit those values in the `deletePhoto` method

Answer (score 0):

Your API call is apparently returning an object (`fetchedProperty`) with a `photos` array that has been sealed via [`Object.seal`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/seal).

You are setting your `property` data property to `Object.assign({}, fetchedProperty)`, which is assigning the value of each property in `fetchedProperty` to an empty array.

This still means that the value of `photos` (which is a sealed array) is getting set to the empty object being assigned to your `property` data property.

You need to explicitly copy the values of the `photos` array and set that to the `photos` property of the data property. Maybe something like this:

```
async asyncData({ params }) {
  const fetchedProperty = await api.properties.findOne(params.id);
  let property = Object.assign({}, fetchedProperty);
  let property.photos = [...fetchedProperty.photos];

  return {
    oldProperty: fetchedProperty,
    property: property
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to delete a sealed Object is using [`slice`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_slice_array.asp) is

```
this.property.photos = this.property.photos.slice(0, idx).concat(this.property.photos.slice(idx + 1));
```

In your function as:

```
async deletePhoto(photoId, driveId, index) {
    this.property.photos = this.property.photos.slice(0, idx).concat(this.property.photos.slice(idx + 1));
    await api.photos.remove(this.property.id, photoId, driveId);
},
```